# Problem finding transition matrix for Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose that a person has a problem with his memory. Every night forgets a certain amount of people that he knew. For example if he knows k people the night before ,then the next morning he will remember 0,1,...,k with probability $1/(k+1)$ each.Also his doctor every morning teach him a new person.If we define as $X_{n}$ the number of people that he knows the n-night before ,we should determine transition probabilities p(i,k) of $X_{n}$ where $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

So I thought that if we claim that he remembers $k$ people then the transition matrix will be a lower triangular matrix , because in the first row we will have the probability $p(0,0)=1$.

Second row $p(1,0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p(1,1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Third row $p(2,0)=\frac{1}{3}$,$p(2,1)=\frac{1}{3}$and $p(2,2)=\frac{1}{2}$. The same way for all the other rows.

My problem is that I'm not sure if I found the correct transition matrix because when I'm trying to calculate stationary distribution I get a vector full of zeros.

Comment: As you’ve described it, the number of states grows without bound, so I don’t think that you can really describe the system with a matrix.

Comment: @amd But is there another way to describe this system or find the transition probabilities?

Comment: @amd The distribution at step $t+1$ given step $t$ is uniform on $\{1,\ldots,t+1\}$; it has nothing to do with a binomial.

Comment: @Jason Ah, you’re right. I misread the question. That makes things even simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the fact that the doctor teaches the man a new person every morning, so you need to shift everything by $1$. So if the man remembers $k$ people one night, the next night he will remember $1,2,\ldots, k,k+1$ with equal probability. Hence the transition probabilities are:

$$p(i,j)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{i+1}&\text{if }j\in\{1,\ldots,i+1\},\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So there is the chance the next morning , with the help of doctor to remember more people (+1) than the previous night?

Comment: According to how you stated the problem, yes.